# No Gui after upgrading from Kubuntu 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, 23.10

Good day,
I upgraded from 23.4 to 23.10 this morning. After the upgrade the boot would get stuck at TPM disabled by bios and I was not able to finish booting up. I went through the Bios settings (HP Elite Desk) and enabled all of the various options that had to be enabled to turn on TPM (Such as VTx, VTd, SGX, TXT) after all of that, boot-up gets stuck at an HP sign if using "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-10 Generic". if I switch to "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-36 Generic" then it will boot without issue. I have tried adding locallevel=3 to grub menu to try to supress the TPM error as opposed to enabling all of the security options and that did not help.
Any help from all of you Linux geniuses would be appreciated.